# When modifying the navbar, how can I render dropdown-menus correctly?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using Bootstrap to create my user interface.

I have a navbar that is relatively tall; the default height of the navbar is 50px and my navbar is 100px. When I render a split button, the menu drop-down doesn't respect the navbar height (the link below illustrates the problem). How do I fix this so that the dropdown renders beneath the button (and not beneath the navbar)?

Also, if anyone has a suggestion on how to get rid of the gap in the middle of the button group, that'd be awesome too!

---

#### Clarification

I'm using SASS so I didn't realize that the link that I pasted didn't illustrate the problem. I compiled my CSS and put it in the JSFiddle link. Unfortunately, the CSS file there is huge.

If you're using BootStrap with LESS or SASS, I adjusted the `$navbar-height` variable to 100px (instead of 50px).

In any case, I'm hoping for some guidance on what the Bootstrap Way™ of adjusting things like the navbar height so this stuff works.

(Old link that doesn't illustrate the problem)
http://www.bootply.com/yOrqxaoM2t

(New link)
http://jsfiddle.net/marvery/VpL9N/1/

Comment: the question is unclear! do you want the navbar dropdown to stay with the height of the navbar?\

Comment: I want the dropdown to render underneath the button.

Comment: it currently is under the button? the question is still unclear.. maybe a mockup will help

Comment: Did you try clicking on the link? I wrote in the problem description that there is a link that illustrates the problem.

Comment: the link does not illustrate any problems. I am confused! is this what you had in mind http://www.bootply.com/LYXkOVYAO1

Comment: I'm sorry @nolawipetros, you're right. I posted a new JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

ok it looks like the issue is not with the navba height its with the margin you have set `margin-bottom:33px` on `.navbar-btn`- that needs to be removed.

```
 .navbar-btn {
    margin-bottom:0px;/* should be zero bootstrap default btn margin- remove yours */ 
 }
```

that is moving the dropdown to be 33px lower than the default
fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VpL9N/2/)